# How do you change the colour of the subtitles in beamer slides (lower title)?

Tags: beamer, color, templates

My question relates to the Beamer templates. I am looking to change the lower title (underneath my name) on my slide but it stays black. I have no idea where to start for this solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
***Packages***
***Commands***
    \usetheme{Berlin}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
\title{Solar Wind: A Mathematician's Perspective}
\author{Kieran}
\begin{document}
\frame {
    \titlepage
}
\frame {
    \frametitle{What are we considering}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Solar Wind 

        \item Analytical Approaches 

        \item Acceleration

    \end{itemize}
}
```

If the problem is believed to have come from packages conflicting - I can add these at a later stage.

[image]

Comment: You should definitely not try to use `titlesec` with beamer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preface

As long as your document compiles with errors (I suspect from the `titlesec` package, but you don't show the code) there is no point in worrying about formatting details like the title colour, in fact you should not look at the broken file -- which might or might not be a valid pdf -- at all.

## Answer

You can control the colour of the title in the footline via `\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=red}`.

Per default it is white, so are doing something in your code which you don't show us .... so if this does not solve your problem, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=red}

\title{title}
\author{names}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame}    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem - I will add some more code to the above question to see if that helps.

Comment: @KieranSQ "Some more" is not enough. You should add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: I found the issue - the package `hyperref' causes issues with the colour scheme.

Comment: @KieranSQ Don't load hyperref, beamer already provides this functionality.